# Crashlytics NDK ClassNotFoundException on CrashlyticsCore when using NDK logging

Tags: android, android-ndk, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'm trying to get logging with Crashlytics-NDK to work on some JNI code in C++, but if I declare and define a `crashlytics_context_t` instance and run the app, I get a

```
ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

with a stacktrace like so:

```
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc E/art: Unexpected exception:
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.nativeLoad(Native Method)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.doLoad(Runtime.java:435)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:370)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at org.xyz.efg.NativeEngine.<clinit>(NativeEngine.java:51)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at org.xyz.efg.AbcService.initializeAbcEngine(AbcService.java:100)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at org.xyz.efg.AbcService.onCreate(AbcService.java:88)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2877)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:         ... 17 more
3139-3139/org.xyz.abc W/System.err:     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

I've declared a `crashlytics_context_t` instance globally as an `extern` in a header file for logging and defined it globally as `crashlytics_context_t* crashlytics_context_1 = crashlytics_init();` in one of the source files.

Crashlytics NDK works fine for standard crash reporting (i.e., without logging in the C/C++ code), and Crashlytics works with logging and key-value pairs perfectly fine in the Java code.

I enabled multidex support since we support API 19 and above. My `build.gradle` file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'org.xyz.abc'
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 5
        versionName '1.1.1'
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                abiFilters "x86", "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "mips"
                arguments "APP_PLATFORM=android-19", "NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk"
            }
        }

    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "src/main/jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            jniDebuggable true
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.6@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

crashlytics {
    enableNdk true
}
```

Comment: Can you make sure you've followed all of the configuration and initialization steps from https://fabric.io/downloads/gradle/ndk?

Comment: Yes, I've done everything on those pages.

Comment: Can you try explicitly excluding architectures in your build.gradle's packagingOptions block that you're not building for?. For example:

packagingOptions { 
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics-envelope.so' 
exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcrashlytics.so' 
exclude 'lib/mips64/libcrashlytics-envelope.so' 
exclude 'lib/mips64/libcrashlytics.so' 
exclude 'lib/mips/libcrashlytics-envelope.so' 
exclude 'lib/mips/libcrashlytics.so' 
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcrashlytics-envelope.so' 
exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcrashlytics.so' 
}

Comment: I've done that, as well as tried with ABI splits - nothing helps. Just adding the header doesn't raise this error - I need to declare and define an instance of `crashlytics_context_t` to cause the error

Comment: If you disable multidex do you still get this error?

Comment: Yup. I'd first built it without multidex, and without minify. Now I've enabled both and added the proguard keep rules as well

Answer (score -4):

Try cleaning your project and rebuild it.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.